# Nginx is downloading the index.php instead of executing - Docker + symfony + php-fpm

Tags: php, docker, nginx, configuration

When I visit "localhost:8000" I get a 403 Forbidden. But, if I go to "localhost:8000/index.php", the file is being downloaded.

I know there is a lot of questions like this around there, but I swear I have checked like 50 I none of those solutions seem to work for me, or maybe I am doing something wrong... I am completely new in Docker, be patient :)

I suspect that the problem is related to the configuration of nginx, or perhaps the php-fpm service is not working or not being able to communicate with nginx service.

These are the related files:

php.conf (nginx configuration file):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /public;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to index.php
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        internal;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
}
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      target: app_php
      args:
        SYMFONY_VERSION: ${SYMFONY_VERSION:-}
        STABILITY: ${STABILITY:-stable}
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - php_socket:/var/run/php
    healthcheck:
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 30s

  webserver:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
        - 8000:80
    volumes:
        - ./nginx/conf.d/php.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/php.conf
        - ./public:/usr/share/nginx/html
    depends_on:
      - php

  mysql:
      image: mysql:8.0
      environment:
          - MYSQL_USER=root
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin
          - MYSQL_DATABASE=db
      volumes:
          - symfony-data:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  php_socket:
  symfony-data:
###> symfony/mercure-bundle ###
###< symfony/mercure-bundle ###


###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
  db-data:
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
```

My proyect folders:

- assets
- bin
- config
- docker
- docs
- migrations
- nginx

  - conf.d

    - php.conf
- node_modules
- public

  - build
  - index.php (this is the file I am downloading, damn u, just run pls)
- src

  - Controller
  - Entity
  - Repository
- templates
- var

  - cache
  - log
    .
    .
    .
- Dockerfile
- docker-compose.yml

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks to everyone!!

I tried a lot of changes in the configuration files of nginx and fpm, as well as the docker-composer file, but nothing works...

Answer (score 0):

add line
index index.php index.html;
in nginx configuration file

```
server {
listen 80;
root /public;
index index.php index.html;

location / {
    # try to serve file directly, fallback to index.php
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass php:9000;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    internal;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    return 404;
}

error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
```

}

Comment: Not working. If I am not mistaken, the default behaviour of the nginx is to look for index.php or index.html files in the folders if they are empty, so I think this line is not necessary. Also, the problem I think is not that the file is not being found, but the file is not being executed, because when I go to "localhost:8000/index.php", the file is there, but it is being downloaded.